# How to prefetch a list of unique values from a related Django model?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I'd like to prefetch a list of unique values from a related model in Django in as few queries as possible.

For instance, consider the following :

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey('B')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    pass
```

I'd like to annotate each model instance of a queryset on B, with a list of unique values from the `value` column in the related A objects.

```
>>> qs = B.objects.all().annotate(distinct_a_values=...)
>>> [a.value for a in qs.first().a_set.all()]
["value_1", "value_2", "value_1"]
>>> qs.first().distinct_a_values
["value_1", "value_2"]
```

The closest I could find was to use a `Prefetch` object :

```
>>> qs = B.objects.all().prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'a_set',
            A.objects.all().distinct('value').only('value', 'b_id'),
            to_attr='distinct_a_values'
        )
    )
```

It works, but feels clunky, and it is definitely weird to get a list of A objects, only to discover that they are distinct on something other than the primary key.

Any other way?

Comment: Any comment about why this was downvoted?

Comment: I don't know why it was down voted.  That said, I think prefetch is the best way to do this.  You don't need the all() part, it's implicitly done.  I would change to running distinct after you run only.